# Is there resource where I can find list of possible errors for specified Windows API function?

Tags: winapi

For example: I'd like to know all possible error numbers for `FindNextFileW` function.

Comment: Try putting the function names into Google. It [may work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew#return-value).

Comment: @GSerg , microsoft docs provide information about only one possible error (ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES), however there is no word that only that error is possible.

Comment: Why you need all possible error numbers? You have result Success or Error. With `GetLastError()` you get code and text of last error - you can log it or show to user. It is not necessary to write logic for each error. Imagine that Win32 is improved and new error code is added in next Windows. How your program will work when you don't know the future error code?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew). It states that the function can fail, for any number of reasons. It then goes on to highlight one relevant error mode.  And no, there is no exhaustive list of all error codes any given API call can return. As noted, that's not very useful either.

Comment: `NOERROR` mean that you got information inside `WIN32_FIND_DATA`, `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` mean that no more matching files can be found. this not error but faster information here - that is the end and you need break loop. this is ok code. all another error values - is real error. you need break enumeration loop too. you can log error but not more here. usually, if you pass correct input parameters to this api - must not be another errors

Comment: @i486 , I'm studying Information Security. I'm programming win api hooking tool. i'm actually hooking FindNextFileW function. My hook should behave like original FindNextFileW. Because of it I'd like to know what errors can FindNextFileW set as last error.

I definitely understand that usually I need just to check returned value as error checking.

Comment: Have your hook call the original function if you want it to behave the same way. Simple answer to your question is no. No such list. Wouldn't be useful to you either. Because knowing what errors can be returned doesn't tell you when they are returned.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I'd like to omit discussing workflow of my hook since it's not the topic of the question. If you are interested in it, I can provide link to repository with some not very beautiful university task:D I'm not agree that " knowing what errors can be returned doesn't tell you when they are returned". For example "ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES" says when it's returned.

Comment: @RbMm "*`NOERROR` mean that you got information inside `WIN32_FIND_DATA`*" - actually no, since the return value of `GetLastError()` is *indeterminate* when `FindNextFileW()` returns TRUE, which is the only indicator that the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` contains valid data.  The return value of `GetLastError()` is valid only when `FindNextFileW()` returns FALSE. And then `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` is one of the possible error codes.

Comment: By the way I'm not asking is it useful or not to know all possible errors of specified win api function. I appreciate you answers and mostly agree with them:) I still have a hope that there is somebody who will provide a link to the unknown resource that will serve me.

Comment: @Roma there is no such resource

Comment: @RemyLebeau - of course. i mean under `NOERROR` that function return true. but didn’t paint things obvious to himself

Comment: @Roma this is also impossible by next reason - `FindNextFileW` call `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` and it call driver code with `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`. custom driver can return any code.. but usually only file system drivers (yet npfs.sys) implement this. and usually we call for ms drivers (ntfs, fat, refs). but formally can be and another driver called here

Comment: Sure, some errors like no more files occur at easily defined times. But plenty more don't. Surely you can see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is no such list.

Unless the documentation for a given API function describes the *exact* error codes that it reports, no more no less (this is very rare!), then you have to assume that ANY error is possible, for ANY reason - ie a filesystem error, a memory error, an OS error, the sky is falling, the world is ending, etc.

Some error codes have specific meaning to individual functions.  Those specific cases are documented.  For instance, the [`FindNextFileW()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) states the following:

> Return value
> -
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero and the `lpFindFileData` parameter contains information about the next file or directory found.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero and the contents of `lpFindFileData` are indeterminate. **To get extended error information, call the `GetLastError` function.**
>
> **If the function fails because no more matching files can be found, the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`.**

That is all you get.  One *possible* error code that has special meaning in a specific circumstance, out of all possible [system error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes) that *could also* happen.

API functions make internal calls to other APIs all the time, and internal implementations can change over time.  Those internal APIs can fail for their own reasons, not related to the function that is calling them.  Errors are propagated up the call stack as needed until someone handles them.  So, for instance, calling `FindNextFileW()` could make many levels of internal function calls that could end up failing at a very low-level that `FindNextFileW()` has no concept of, and so such errors could not be documented in the context of `FindNextFileW()` anyway.